# Difference between array<T> and array<T^> where T is ValueType

Tags: c#, arrays, c++-cli

I'm writing a C++/CLI wrapper over native lib for my C# project. I'm trying to convert std::vector<unsigned char> in native c++ to System.Byte[] in C#.
In C++/CLI both variants are valid

```cpp
auto arr = gcnew array<System::Byte>(10);
auto arr = gcnew array<System::Byte^>(10);
```

But in first case in C# code we got System::Byte[] type whereas in second case we got System::ValueType[].

So my question is why we got such strange behavior?

Comment: Not my strong suit, but I believe in the first example you're declaring an array of `byte` as you would expect. The second example is declaring an array of boxed bytes (a value type) so that you can have references.

Comment: Stupid me. Probably you're right. I was confused because when you are creating System.Byte using new keyword in C# i.e. new Byte() boxing is not happening. And I was guessing that when you call gcnew System::Byte() (in c++/cli) which fit the second array i've described above, there will be same behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` hat should only be used on reference types.  Byte is a value type so `array<System::Byte>` is the proper declaration.

Unfortunately C++/CLI *also* permits an array of `Byte^`, turning a value into an object is a supported scenario in .NET code.  The array now contains references to objects, the object is the *boxed* value of the byte.  Boxing conversions implement the famous illusion that value types inherit from System::ValueType which derives from System::Object.  Instead of 1 byte of storage for an element, you now need 4 bytes for the object reference and 12 bytes for the boxed byte object in 32-mode.

Well, don't do that.  I've never yet encountered a scenario where this was necessary or useful.  There are a few scenarios where boxing is necessary, Reflection for example, but it then makes more sense to go directly to Object^ since that's the way such methods are documented.